# Vue Cool Lightbox - TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, lightbox

I have an image gallery and i use the component "[vue-cool-lightbox](https://github.com/lucaspulliese/vue-cool-lightbox)".
When we click on an picture, a lightbox appears on the same picture, that worked fine when my "projects" was not dynamically loaded by axios.

Now, all pictures are loaded, but when I click on it, the lightbox doesnt appear and i have this message :
[image]

My file :

```
<template>
    <div id="photos" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h2>Photos</h2>
                    <div class="divider-c"> <span></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <CoolLightBox 
        :items="projects" 
        :index="index"
        @close="index = null">
        </CoolLightBox>

        <div class="title-container">
            <div class="filters">
                <span class="filter" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'TOUTES' }" v-on:click="setFilter('TOUTES')">Toutes</span>
                <span class="filter" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'MUSICIENS' }" v-on:click="setFilter('MUSICIENS')">Musiciens</span>
                <span class="filter" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'SCENE' }" v-on:click="setFilter('SCENE')">Scène</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <transition-group class="row images-wrapper projects" name="projects" style="margin:0;">

                <!-- eslint-disable -->
                    <div
                        class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 image_list"
                        v-for="(project, imageIndex) in projects"
                        v-if="currentFilter === project.categorie || currentFilter === 'TOUTES'" 
                        :key="imageIndex"
                        @click="index = imageIndex"
                        :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url('+url_admin+'/images/_gallery/'+project.url_image + ')', cursor: 'zoom-in' }"
                    ></div>
                <!-- eslint-enable -->
                
        </transition-group> 
        


    </div>
</template>
<script>
import CoolLightBox from 'vue-cool-lightbox';
import 'vue-cool-lightbox/dist/vue-cool-lightbox.min.css'
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'Photos',
    components: {
        CoolLightBox,
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            currentFilter: 'TOUTES',
            projects: [],
            url_admin: process.env.VUE_APP_ADMIN_URL,
            index: null
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        axios
        .get(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL+'/getPhotos')
        .then(response => (this.projects = response.data.data))
    },
    methods: {
        setFilter: function(filter) {
            this.currentFilter = filter;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

So, when i click on my picture (v-for inside my ), the div  should open the lightbox, but that not work.

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing nothing to CoolLightBox you should check if data is fetched from server and then render the component maybe like :

```
        <CoolLightBox 
        v-if="projects.length > 0"
        :items="projects" 
        :index="index"
        @close="index = null">
        </CoolLightBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered same issue, I was able to solved it by following the array of objects the same way with the examples provided in the documentation:

```
items: [
    {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      src: ""
    }
]
```